# Why many unnecessary comment signs // appear in my VIM after copying codes?

Tags: vim, format, copy, vi

```
/*
 * This file contains code from "C++ Primer, Fifth Edition", by Stanley B.
 * Lippman, Josee Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo, and is covered under the
 * copyright and warranty notices given in that book:
 * 
 * "Copyright (c) 2013 by Objectwrite, Inc., Josee Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo."
 * 
 * 
 * "The authors and publisher have taken care in the preparation of this book,
 * but make no expressed or implied warranty of any kind and assume no
 * responsibility for errors or omissions. No liability is assumed for
 * incidental or consequential damages in connection with or arising out of the
 * use of the information or programs contained herein."
 * 
 * Permission is granted for this code to be used for educational purposes in
 * association with the book, given proper citation if and when posted or
 * reproduced.Any commercial use of this code requires the explicit written
 * permission of the publisher, Addison-Wesley Professional, a division of
 * Pearson Education, Inc. Send your request for permission, stating clearly
 * what code you would like to use, and in what specific way, to the following
 * address: 
 * 
 *     Pearson Education, Inc.
 *     Rights and Permissions Department
 *     One Lake Street
 *     Upper Saddle River, NJ  07458
 *     Fax: (201) 236-3290
*/ 

/* This file defines the Sales_item class used in chapter 1.
 * The code used in this file will be explained in
 * Chapter 7 (Classes) and Chapter 14 (Overloaded Operators)
 * Readers shouldn't try to understand the code in this file
 * until they have read those chapters.
*/

#ifndef SALESITEM_H
// we're here only if SALESITEM_H has not yet been defined 
#define SALESITEM_H

// Definition of Sales_item class and related functions goes here
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Sales_item {
// these declarations are explained section 7.2.1, p. 270 
// and in chapter 14, pages 557, 558, 561
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Sales_item&);
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Sales_item&);
friend bool operator<(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
friend bool 
operator==(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
public:
    // constructors are explained in section 7.1.4, pages 262 - 265
    // default constructor needed to initialize members of built-in type
    Sales_item() = default;
    Sales_item(const std::string &book): bookNo(book) { }
    Sales_item(std::istream &is) { is >> *this; }
public:
    // operations on Sales_item objects
    // member binary operator: left-hand operand bound to implicit this pointer
    Sales_item& operator+=(const Sales_item&);

    // operations on Sales_item objects
    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    double avg_price() const;
// private members as before
private:
    std::string bookNo;      // implicitly initialized to the empty string
    unsigned units_sold = 0; // explicitly initialized
    double revenue = 0.0;
};

// used in chapter 10
inline
bool compareIsbn(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs) 
{ return lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn(); }

// nonmember binary operator: must declare a parameter for each operand
Sales_item operator+(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);

inline bool 
operator==(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs)
{
    // must be made a friend of Sales_item
    return lhs.units_sold == rhs.units_sold &&
           lhs.revenue == rhs.revenue &&
           lhs.isbn() == rhs.isbn();
}

inline bool 
operator!=(const Sales_item &lhs, const Sales_item &rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs); // != defined in terms of operator==
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same ISBN
Sales_item& Sales_item::operator+=(const Sales_item& rhs) 
{
    units_sold += rhs.units_sold; 
    revenue += rhs.revenue; 
    return *this;
}

// assumes that both objects refer to the same ISBN
Sales_item 
operator+(const Sales_item& lhs, const Sales_item& rhs) 
{
    Sales_item ret(lhs);  // copy (|lhs|) into a local object that we'll return
    ret += rhs;           // add in the contents of (|rhs|) 
    return ret;           // return (|ret|) by value
}

std::istream& 
operator>>(std::istream& in, Sales_item& s)
{
    double price;
    in >> s.bookNo >> s.units_sold >> price;
    // check that the inputs succeeded
    if (in)
        s.revenue = s.units_sold * price;
    else 
        s = Sales_item();  // input failed: reset object to default state
    return in;
}

std::ostream& 
operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Sales_item& s)
{
    out << s.isbn() << " " << s.units_sold << " "
        << s.revenue << " " << s.avg_price();
    return out;
}

double Sales_item::avg_price() const
{
    if (units_sold) 
        return revenue/units_sold; 
    else 
        return 0;
}
#endif
```

I want to **copy the above code into my VIM**.

First I **choose** everything, then **ctrl-c**, then go to my VIM editor, **switch** to insert mode and **right click** and finally **paste**.

What actually is copied in my VIM is not correct.

A lot of unnecessary // appear there. See following.

[image]

**Why does that happen?**

**How can I copy long code like that into VIM correctly ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:set paste`, copy, `:set nopaste`. See `:help 'paste'`. EDIT: Also `:help 'pastetoggle'`, while you're at it.

Basically, you are using a dumb terminal (that's a technical term, not a character assassination *) that doesn't know what "paste" is. Thus, when you paste, the terminal just gets a stream of characters. Vim interprets those characters as input; if you are in normal mode, it tries to execute them as commands. If in insert mode, it thinks you're typing them.

What's wrong with that? The problem is that you have some options active that are there to help you; for example, `autoindent` to indent your code, `formatoptions` to continue comments in next line etc. It all works well when it's actually you typing: if you don't want to continue your comment, you can cancel it. Dumb terminal just keeps on typing, and Vim can't know it's not you that is in control.

Thus, `:set paste` - the paste mode will disable all the "helpful features" that might interfere with a pasting operation.

If you have a not-dumb terminal that your Vim can talk to (e.g. MacVim on local Terminal on OSX), Vim knows that you're pasting and does the right thing automatically, so the whole `paste` schtick is not needed.

---

*) "Dumb terminal" actually means something even dumber, originally, but it's close enough for the purpose of this explanation.